# SQLite, showing column totals as rows

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm using version System.Data.SQLite 1.0.105.2

I have a row which includes a column called total_count, for example if this had a value of 22 I'd like to create a select query which would return 22 rows as a result.
This link shows what I'm after, the solution appears to be incompatible with the SQLite.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb57e/1

Is this possible using this system?

Thanks.

Comment: This would be possible with a recursive CTE. But what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to duplicate each row depending on the value of a column.

Considering a schema like this one, where id is a primary key :

```
create table test_table (id integer primary key, total_count integer);
```

You could write something like :

```
WITH RECURSIVE
   nb_rows(id, total_count, idx) AS (
      SELECT id, total_count, 1 FROM test_table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT test_table.id, test_table.total_count, idx+1
      FROM nb_rows, test_table
      WHERE test_table.id=nb_rows.id AND idx < test_table.total_count
   )
   SELECT test_table.*
   FROM test_table, nb_rows
   WHERE nb_rows.id = test_table.id;
```

If you're calling that request from another language you should consider to do this programmatically (duplicating the row with some "for" loop in the calling code).

Answer (score -1):

You can use **count()** function to get *total_count*

Reference Link http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/tryit/query/sqlite-count-function/#1

Comment: not quite what I'm after. I have a row like this

test   3

What I'd like to translate this into is this:

test   3
test   3
test   3